# Error while opening Spectacle

Tags: package-management, kde, kde5, screenshot, kde-neon

PrntScrn doesn't work and trying to open spectacle window with the command line gives me the following error:

```bsh
$ spectacle
spectacle: error while loading shared libraries: libkColorPicker.so.0.1.4: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I am using KDE Neon btw. It comes with spectacle preinstalled but there is also a snap package available so i tried installing that and it opens fine but this one doesn't. Any way to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
$ sudo apt install libkcolorpicker0=0.1.4-1+20.04+focal+build1
```

Comment: as soon as i do this, I get an update on Discover telling me that I need to update the same package. When I do update, spectacle stops working again.

Answer (score 1):

```
ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libkColorPicker.so.0.1.5 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libkColorPicker.so.0.1.4
```

as a temporary solution

Comment: can you explain what this code does

Comment: spectacle is trying to find libkColorPicker.so.0.1.4, but it is not exists, so application failed to start. ln -s creates symbolic link from version 0.1.5, which exists, to libkColorPicker.so.0.1.4 as alias. With such subsctitution spectacle works well

Comment: Thank you. Spectacle just got an update and now it works perfectly.